# How do diacritical marks impact centering and overshooting?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, typography

I am creating a table containing several foreign names with [diacritical marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) in them, and it seems to me that they ruin the vertical alignment, as they are too close to the top horizontal line. How should I center these correctly? Is the fictional acronym `O\'O\"O\H{O}` correctly rendered from [overshooting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306061/why-do-the-subscript-numbers-look-misaligned) point of view, or should one bump the leading letter `O` a bit higher?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\"Ostersund & \AA m\aa l & Oxel\"osund & Alings\aa s & \'Orlaith &O\'O\"O\H{O}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using `booktabs` package with `\toprule` instead of `\hline` works.

Comment: I have checked, and -- in the way you described -- it does *not* work. Now the vertical bars are not tall enough.

Comment: With booktabs it works without the vertical rules, which that package discourages. For every table-related question here, someone will tell you to use booktabs and avoid vertical rules, even though that's not always the best answer. But booktabs does implement better spacing around its horizontal rules.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the best way to proceed is to stop using `\hline` -- and, while you're at it, ditch all vertical bars -- and to use the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package. For the table at hand, `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` should be used.

If, for some reason, you simply must use vertical bars (and hence can't use `\toprule` and `\bottomrule`), I suggest you load the `array` package and set the length of `\extrarowheight` to something like `2pt` or `3pt`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\begin{document}

%% original form
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\"Ostersund & \AA m\aa l & Oxel\"osund & Alings\aa s & \'Orlaith & O\'O\"O\H{O}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\medskip
%% with rule-drawing macros of the booktabs package
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\toprule
\"Ostersund & \AA m\aa l & Oxel\"osund & Alings\aa s & \'Orlaith & O\'O\"O\H{O}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}


\medskip
%% with \extrarowheight set to 3pt
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\"Ostersund & \AA m\aa l & Oxel\"osund & Alings\aa s & \'Orlaith & O\'O\"O\H{O}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

The problem is not in diacritics, it is in LaTeX  tables. You can give rows some vertical padding with the `cellspace` package, which ensure a *minimal* vertical distance between a cell and the above and below rules.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array, cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{tabular}{|*{6}{Sc|}}
\hline
\"Ostersund & \AA m\aa l & Oxel\"osund & Alings\aa s & \'Orlaith &O\'O\"O\H{O}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Insert a large `\strut`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
{\Large\strut}\"Ostersund & \AA m\aa l & Oxel\"osund & Alings\aa s & \'Orlaith &O\'O\"O\H{O}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's clever! I will look into this [strutness](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41185/strutting-around-whats-the-difference-between-strut-mathstrut-and-vphantom).

Comment: Since `\strut` has both height and depth, it'll also increase the amount of whitespace *below* the baseline; this may or may not be desirable. Can you suggest how to create a top-strut (only height, but no depth) to handle the typographic issue?

Answer (score 2):

**OPTION 1:** Row specific padding

One can add a `\stackgap` to a given element of the line, which pads the element vertically by the amount of the optional argument (default 3pt).  The MWE below shows 3 rows that have been padded with 1pt, 3pt, and 5pt, respectively.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\addstackgap[1pt]{\"Ostersund} & \AA m\aa l & Oxel\"osund & Alings\aa s & \'Orlaith &O\'O\"O\H{O}\\
\hline
\addstackgap[3pt]{\"Ostersund} & \AA m\aa l & Oxel\"osund & Alings\aa s & \'Orlaith &O\'O\"O\H{O}\\
\hline
\addstackgap[5pt]{\"Ostersund} & \AA m\aa l & Oxel\"osund & Alings\aa s & \'Orlaith &O\'O\"O\H{O}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**OPTION  2:** Uniform (and automatic) padding

Another way, if the same padding is wanted for each row, is to use `tabularx` and the `>{}` feature to automatically pad the contents, specifically here,

```
>{\addstackgap[2pt]{\vphantom{\"Xg}}}
```

which adds a 2pt buffer to something the height and depth of `\"Xg`, which was chosen to represent the vertical extent of typical diacritically modified text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{tabular}{|>{\addstackgap[2pt]{\vphantom{\"Xg}}}c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\"Ostersund & \AA m\aa l & Oxel\"osund & Alings\aa s & \'Orlaith &O\'O\"O\H{O}\\
\hline
\"Ostersund & \AA m\aa l & Oxel\"osund & Alings\aa s & \'Orlaith &O\'O\"O\H{O}\\
\hline
\"Ostersund & \AA m\aa l & Oxel\"osund & Alings\aa s & \'Orlaith &O\'O\"O\H{O}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do I know how much padding is needed? Or is this a trial-and-error approach?

Comment: @Matsmath It is an aesthetic preference.  So find a value you like and stick with it.

Comment: @Matsmath I have added a 2nd option, as well.