# How to remove extra vertical space between vertically merged cells?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

Following [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307538/how-do-diacritical-marks-impact-centering-and-overshooting), I have used the `array` package and `\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}` to slightly heighten the rows in the table below in order to make room for the diacritical marks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\"Ostersund & Married\\
\cline{1-1}
\'Orlaith & Couple\\
\hline
Twin & \AA m\aa l\\
\cline{2-2}
Peaks & O\'O\"O\H{O}\\
\hline
\'Acs & Anders\\
\cline{1-1}
\H{O}riszentp\'eter & Jonas\\
\cline{1-1}
\'Ujsz\'asz & \AA ngstr\"om\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This, however, resulted in the somewhat inconvenient side effects, that in vertically merged cells subsequent rows are now (1) too far away from each other and (2) the contents are *not* vertically centered (as the rows are now closer to the (perhaps hidden) cell-separator immediately below them).

How can I specify the text height between the lines of the vertically merged cells and have their contents vertically (and horizontally) centered?

---

Related: [How to vertically-center the text of the cells?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7208/how-to-vertically-center-the-text-of-the-cells)

Comment: You can do a patch by creating an invisible line, say `\def\trule#1#2{\vrule height #1 depth #2 width 0ex}`, with the desired depth and height like `\trule{3ex}{1ex}` and add this to all rows that require a change in row height but using `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}` would do. Note that the command `\trule{<height>}{<depth>}` will only affect the rows in which you apply it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `makecell`package, and its `multirowcell` command, which allow for multiline  cells. I added `cellspace`, which define *minimal* vertical padding at the top and bottom of cells in column with specifier prefixed with the `letter`. And finally, using `utf8` encoding for your code and a T1` encoded font, you can directly type accented letters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow, array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \begin{tabular}{|Sc|Sc|}
    \hline
    Östersund & Married \\
    \cline{1-1}
    Órlaith & Couple \\
    \hline
    \multirowcell{2}[-1.2pt]{Twin \\Peaks} &Åmål \\
    \cline{2-2}
    & OÓÖŐ \\
    \hline
    Ács & \multirowcell{3}[-3pt]{Anders \\ Jonas\\ Ångström} \\
    \cline{1-1}
    Őriszentpéter & \\
    \cline{1-1}
    Újszász & \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks elegant. However, may I suggest a light edit to your text? It seems that a backtick might be missing, and as you switched to unicode there are some unnecessary spaces in the word Amal (cf. rendered output).

Comment: @Matsmath: It's corrected now. Thanks for pointing it!